# Very basic two column layout. Why does the second column span behind the first?

Tags: html, css

I have a very basic two column layout. The first column has a background color of white, the second is green. I'm doing it very simply via:

```
#col1 { 
  background-color: white; 
  float: left; 
}

#col2 { 
  background-color: green
}

<div id="col1">

</div>
<div id="col2">
  <!-- green background, and needs to fill up the remaining width, so i can't float left */ 
</div>
```

Why does column two span across the entire width of the page and sit behind column one? I'd just like two columns, one of a fixed width, the second one to use up the rest of the page.

Seems so simple. Is there a better way to do this?

Here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yrkrJ/1/

Comment: Life was so much easier when I could use tables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you define **float** to your first DIV. So, the second div is not recognized the height. Write like this

```
#col2 {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yrkrJ/4/

Read this for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Appreciate the extra read that helps explain it. I guess the old solution was to use clear: both, now I use this overflow trick.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now give to `overflow:hidden`

as like this

```
#header-banner {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yrkrJ/3/)***